# Table columns (by group) into json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a dataset stored on postgresql, where each sku (grouped by stores) has different start date:

```
     date        sku     store   Units     Vx
0  2019-10-01  103993.0    001    0.0       F
1  2019-10-02  103993.0    001    1.0       F
2  2019-10-03  103993.0    001    0         F
3  2019-10-04  103993.0    001    1.0       F 
4  2019-10-05  103993.0    001    0         F

5  2019-10-02  103994.0    002    1.0       F
5  2019-10-03  103994.0    002    0         F
6  2019-10-04  103994.0    002    1.0       F
7  2019-10-05  103994.0    002    0.0       F
```

I need to convert each group into a unique json file, where:

1-  Date column: It takes the first date

2 - Store and Vx column: It takes the unique non null value into a single list

3 - Units column: return the whole column as a list

Expected output:

```
{"date":"2019-10-01", "join_store_Vx":[001, F],"Units":[0.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 0]}

{"date":"2019-10-01", "join_store_Vx":[002, F],"Units":[1.0, 0, 1.0, 0.0]}
```

I just found examples using postgresql function `row_to_json`

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are the problems you face with it?

Comment: The only way I know how to solve this is using python, creating many small queries, and converting into a json file.

Comment: I would like to know if it possible to do it directly on postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8f053a7e60825577a9639fa584458d1f)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(
        'date', min("date"),
        'join_store_Vx', json_build_array(store, "Vx"),
        'Units', json_agg("Units")
    )
FROM mytable
GROUP BY store, "Vx"
```

1. Group by `store` and `Vx`
2. Aggregate functions: `MIN()` for `date`, `ARRAY_AGG()` for the `Units`
3. `json_build_array()` for putting `store` and `Vx` into one array
4. Create a JSON object and wrap it around your results

Comment: They want a JSON array and that is capable of using mixed types. `json_build_array(store, vx)` instead of `array_to_json(ARRAY[store::text, "Vx"])` should work.

Comment: Great one! Didn't know about it. Changed it!

Comment: @S-Man, if I want to export as a json file in the end, what approach do you recommend ?